# Как передать файл(фото) методом POST в файл php, и сохранить его на сервер, используя чистый Javascript и Php?

Tags: javascript, php, post

У меня есть форма, где есть инпут поля, и загрузка файла. Я должен отправить данные формы методом POST. Я это делаю через formData. Записываю в formData данные загруженного файла и отправляю в файл php. И затем должен записать файл на сервер, но что-то почему-то не получается. Вот код:

```js
async function formSend(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    formValidate();
    
    let formData = new FormData(form);
  //поулчаю поле загрузки файла
    let inpFile = document.querySelector('#load_img');
  
    if(error==0){
        const idProduct = localStorage.getItem("productID");
        localStorage.removeItem("productID");
        formData.append("id", idProduct);
      
      //доабвляю в формдата загруженный файл
        formData.append("inpFile", inpFile.files[0]);
      
      const response = await fetch('./adminSendChangeProduct.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });
      if(response.ok){
        form.reset();
        alert("Изменения внесены корректно");
        window.location.href = "./adminProducts.php?check='test'";
      }
      else{
        alert("Ошибка");
      }
  }
  else{
    alert("Заполните обязательные поля");
  }
}
```

```html
Вот так получаю в файле php.
Но файл не отправляется на сервер. 
Может я что-то делаю не так?

$targetPath = "../images/" . basename($_POST["inpFile"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_POST["inpFile"]["tmp_name"], $targetPath);
```

Comment: Файлы приходят в массиве `$_FILES`

Comment: а если методом post?

Comment: Даже если отправляешь методом POST.

Comment: понял, спасибо огромное, вы помогли!